# How would I toggle this html when user mouses over div element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to show the following button on hover and remove it when the user mouses away. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()) {
$('div.service-item').hover().toggle().html('<br /><a href='order/products' class='button'>Get Started</a>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your function is doing is triggering the hover event for 'div.service-item' (i.e. doing nothing) and then toggling it (probably removing it).  You want to do this:

```
$("div.service-item").hover(function () {
      $(this).html("<br /><a href='order/products' class='button'>Get Started</a>");
   },
   function () {
      $(this).html("");
   }
);
```

However, it would probably be better to just do this with css.  Just always have that html in the div, hidden, and display it on `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

See the [jQuery API for .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$('div.service-item').hover(function() {
    // Hover in
}, function() {
    // Hover out
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()) {
    $('div.service-item').bind("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).toggle().html('<br /><a href="order/products" class="button">Get Started</a>');
    });
}
</script>
```

You also had typos in your link.